# How to auto renew SSL certificates in Azure Key Vault with sslforfee after 90 days?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault

Is it possible to auto-renew certificates after 90 days so I don't have to do it manually every time? It doesn't have to be sslforfree as long as it is for free.

Answer (score 2):

Auto-renewal of certificates in Azure Key Vault is supported for integrated CAs only - currently that's DigiCert and GlobalSign. For other non-integrated CAs (sslforfree, for example), you can receive an email notification as the certificate approaches expiration, at which point you can manually renew it.

I have to imagine that there would be a way to script the renewal process on the CA provider side, and then use REST APIs or Az Powershell or AZ CLI to import the script, so as to at least partly automate the process.